# Cargo Ship From Helsinki to Norway?

Tags: international-travel, iceland, helsinki, freighter-travel, scandinavia

I should like t travel by ship from Helsinki to Norway, but prefer cargo instead of cruise ships. In Norway, the Hurtiguten line runs ships along the western coadst of Norway, stopping at ports along the way. It used to be a cargo and mail ship but is now more of a cruise. Is there something like tht in Finland> Can one take a cargo ship from Helsinki to Stockholm and then to Oslo? From Oslo, I should like to continue to Iceland.

A friend told me that she has done it a few years ago, but she is unable to give me details.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is a question about going to Norway considered a duplicate of one about going to Iceland?

Comment: @jpatokal: Both questions ask about traveling _from Helsinki to Iceland by cargo ship_. This one wants _additionally_ to stop in Oslo along the way, which is kind of strange, though.